# What is causing Cocoapods/RedditKit to not work with version 0.39?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I've updated to version 0.39 of Cocoapods per the persistent recommendation in the terminal, and I'm using [RedditKit](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit), an Objective-C wrapper for the Reddit API in an app I'm playing around with.

It's installed through Cocoapods, and I've never had an issue, but since updating to Cocoapods version 0.39 it will not compile any longer, even in a small sample project such as what's included with the repo.

I keep getting "RKClient.h not found" as the compile error, but the file is very clearly there in the Pods folder - I can command-click it!

Was there a big change in 0.39 of Cocoapods that stops it from recognizing files that it would previously? A syntactical issue in my Podfile? How would I fix this to allow the project to compile? (Note, I cannot just revert Cocoapods to a previous version unfortunately.)

Comment: Have you resolved it?